# Hide/Show Toolbar programmatically on CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview

When I scroll my `RecycleView` `ToolBar` hide or show (with animation).
[image]

How I can return `ToolBar` back programmatically?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If your toolbar is inside an AppBarLayout which is probably inside your CoordinatorLayout then something like this should work.

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBar);
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
```

Or to collapse it

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBar);
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
```

Here is the definition

```
setExpanded(boolean expanded, boolean animate)
```

Take note that this method is available from v23 of the support library, here is some [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean)) for reference, the key thing to note is "**As with AppBarLayout's scrolling, this method relies on this layout being a direct child of a CoordinatorLayout.**"

Comment: I have tried these, still not working.  better solution is show and hide the CollapsingToolbar  and set the AppBarLayout params dynamically.      

Do this when ever you show/hide the CollapsingToolbarLayout

mAppBar.setLayoutParams(new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Answer (score 11):

**Is that what you looking for?**

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  // or however you need to do it for your code
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(0);  // clear all scroll flags
```

link: [How to enable/disable toolbar scrolling programmatically when using design support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127720/how-to-enable-disable-toolbar-scrolling-programmatically-when-using-design-suppo)

**In order to hide the Toolbar your can just do something like this:**

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

**If you want to show it again you call:**

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

Comment: @johnarao07 hi man! Thanks for answer but it doesn't work for me. And this solution disable hiding/showing for toolbar. I want just show/hide whithout disabling

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko did you solve your problem? I am facing similar issue

Answer (score 4):

My problem was very similar to @Artem I tried many fix but none of them worked for me. @Jraco11's answer is correct when you use `AppBarLayout`. @johnrao07 not worked for me. But I found a perfect solution for this problem when we use `Toolbar`.

**To hide Toolbar programatically**

```
if (toolbar.getParent() instanceof AppBarLayout){
                    ((AppBarLayout)toolbar.getParent()).setExpanded(false,true);
                }
```

**To show Toolbar programatically**

```
if (toolbar.getParent() instanceof AppBarLayout){
                        ((AppBarLayout)toolbar.getParent()).setExpanded(true,true);
```

***Refer original answer(answer by @Android HHT):-*** [programmatically-show-toolbar-after-hidden-by-scrolling-android-design-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969559/programmatically-show-toolbar-after-hidden-by-scrolling-android-design-library)